# What is declarative data binding?

Tags: javascript

All modern JavaScript frameworks seem to agree upon declarative data binding, and I've noticed it being talked about recently. Can somebody please explain it to me in simple terms?

Comment: That is a rather generic term, Bruno's answer is one of its applications. Also, two-way declarative data binding usually refers to MVVM architectures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically it binds javascript variables to fields

Some pseudo-code

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="{ personObj.hasStuff }" />
```